# How to accumulate all results using AngularJS promise chaining with map() function

Tags: angularjs, typescript, google-api, google-calendar-api

I cannot figure out the proper way to get the data via Google API.

Here is the example: I have a component with a controller and a service:

In my controller I have a method that calls a service to get the data:

```
getCalendarEvents() {
    this.service.getCalendarEvents().then(events => {
        this.calendarEvents = events;
        //this.$scope.$apply();
    });
}
```

In my service, I have a method with the same name to retrieve the data:

```
getCalendarEvents() {
    return gapi.client.calendar.calendarList.list().then(response => {
        if (response.result.items === undefined) return [];
        let requests = response.result.items.map(calendar => {
            let params = { calendarId: calendar.id, timeMin: (new Date()).toISOString(), showDeleted: false, singleEvents: true, maxResults: 10 };
            return gapi.client.calendar.events.list(params)
                .then(response => {
                    let events: any = response.result.items;
                    return events.map(event => {
                        let calendarEvent: CalendarEvent = {
                            id: event.id,
                            summary: event.summary,
                            htmlLink: event.htmlLink,
                            start: new Date(event.start.date == undefined ? event.start.dateTime == undefined ? '' : event.start.dateTime : event.start.date),
                            end: new Date(event.end.date == undefined ? event.end.dateTime == undefined ? '' : event.end.dateTime : event.end.date)
                        };
                    });
                });

        });
        return this.$q.all(requests);
    });
}
```

What its doing is making a call to Google API first to retrieve all calendars of current user:

```
gapi.client.calendar.calendarList.list()
```

then, for each calendar in returned list, I need to make calls to retrieve events associated with this calendar by calendar.id property as a parameter for sending a request to get the events:

```
gapi.client.calendar.events.list(params)
```

All these calls are based on promises. 
I need to return a promise to the controller that will return all events for all calendars.

So, lets say, I have 3 calendars: My Calendar (A), My Brother's calendar (B) and Birthdays calendar (C).
So if I have 5 events in calendar A, 3 events in calendar B and 2 events in calendar C, I must return a promise with 10 events together.

I am using map() function to combine responses together, but in my controller I am receiving back 3 arrays of events (for 3 calendars). Instead I want to receive just 1 array with 10 events, as I explained previously.

**What am I doing wrong?**

[image]

[image]

Comment: `$q.all` returns a single promise that is going to be resolved with an array of values and each value corresponds to the promise at the same index in the `requests` promises array. So this is normal, that you are receiving array of arrays in your controller. As assumption, you can try returning modified result, something like this `return this.$q.all(requests).then(res => { return [].concat.apply([], res); });` could work if `result` is array of event arrays.